# clear votes greater than 50 php script

Tags: php, mysql

I only want to reset votes greater than 50, currently is resets every one

```
    <?
include('mysql_connect.php');
$query = "SELECT id, votes, callback FROM websites";
$result = mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error());
$query = "UPDATE websites SET votes = 0";
$result = mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);


echo ('Database has been cleaned with a tissue.');
?>
```

Im used to coding Java so im not sure if i can use this

```
$query = "UPDATE websites WHERE votes >= 50 SET votes = 0";
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: SET goes before WHERE. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're close. Do this instead.

```
$query = "UPDATE websites SET votes = 0 WHERE votes >= 50 ";
```

Also `mysql_*` functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used.

Comment: Thank you to both of you & @OllyTenerife . I looked into PDO and Mysqli , but they seem by far more complicated :|

Comment: @Toplistrs at least look at mysqli. It is nearly identical in syntax. It can't be that much more complicated.

Comment: I'll try and find some spare time this week and see if i can start converting , page at a time , I guess =]

Comment: Im a little confused about the cron system  , see image:  http://prntscr.com/7hr5yv

I want it to run on the 1st of every month, im confused why its saying 1st of every month, every day?

Comment: It seems you have a new question. You should start a new question instead of asking it under the comments and we will be glad to help.

Comment: Not to worry i have figured it out. Will mark this now

Answer (score 2):

You need the WHERE statement after the SET:

```
$query = "UPDATE websites SET votes = 0 WHERE votes >= 50";
```

Comment: Thank you to both of you & @Dipen Shah